# Android Fragment Manager changes behaviour of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, fragmentmanager

I'm wondering of next - when Fragment Manager removes and add new fragment - Navigation Toggle Button does not respond on taps.

**Details**
1. I have navigation drawer in my project. It was created through standard Android studio project (with navigation drawer).
2. I use fragments and fragment manager to handle screen's content. It happens in onNavigationDrawerItemSelected().
3. Here is implementation of onCreateOptionsMenu() in MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.right_item);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

4. When I use FragmentManager.replace() - everything is ok.
When I use remove() and then add() - Navigation Drawer Toggle button does not respond to taps. I still can press it - but Drawer is not opened at this time. Code in FragmentManager:

```
.beginTransaction()
.remove(fragmentManager.getFragments().get(0))
.commit();

.beginTransaction()
.add(container, replacingFragment)
.commit();
```

Note - I don't override any menu methods in fragments classes.
May be I use wrong code to work with fragments?

The reason why I would prefer remove/add instead of replace - when user select item in Navigation Drawer, which use the same fragment - fragment's content should be updated; and replace() doesn't do it to fragment.

*But it's really strange for me, that operations in Fragment Manager spoil Toggle button.*

**More.** In this case, onOptionsItemSelected() is called in MainActivity and is not called in NavigationDrawerFragment fragment.

**Edit** 
xml file is standard, created by Android studio

```
    <!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg1" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start|left"
        android:name="com.datingappanrdoid.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" >
    </fragment>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Steps to reproduce strange behaviour:
1. In Android studio create new project - select "Project with navigation drawer".
2. Change onNavigationDrawerItemSelected method from replace() to remove() and add(). Here is what I mean:

```
 @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
//                .commit();

        if (tempFragment != null)
            tempFragment.setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .remove(fragmentManager.getFragments().get(0))
                .commit();

        tempFragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        tempFragment.setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, tempFragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

I also added usage of hasOptionsMenu, as it was suggested in comments.
3. Ready - now navigation toggle button is not working on tap (but it's still tapped).

Still have no understanding, why this is happening.

Comment: can you show us your xml file? the one from the activity where you have the navigation drawer defined

Comment: added xml, but it's standard

Comment: ya, I normally don't use fragment in the navigation drawer, I just use a normal layout (like a scrool view), never encountered that problem

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `add()` or `remove()`, new fragment is added/removed. If we want to give `navigation drawer options` to this fragment, we need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(boolean value)` from code

we shall call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` **after** `add()` and shall call `setHasOptionsMenu(false)` **before** `remove()`

This will solve your problem

Comment: May be I'm doing something wrong, but it's not working. A little bit later I'll put test project somewhere to confirm it.

Comment: Added STR to initial answer, still no result.